# how to add link in windows form to open another File (.txt or .img)?

Tags: c#, winforms

In My Windows form i want to add buttons or links , clicking on those will redirect me to open another page (.txt file and .img file) . How to do that ?

Comment: try something 1st! Stackoverflow is not made to do ur homework..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your eventhandler you can directly call: `Process.Start("C:\\myText.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to *Nitin's* answer, it started working for me after adding the *"@"* like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(**@**"C:\\myText.txt");
```